# i want to use without public static word into function

Tags: php, laravel

I have create new class and create hello_world function but my issue is when i have remove public static word in function then does not call 
     function

```
<?php 
class Helpers
        {
            public static function hello_world()
            {
                return 'Hello World';
            }   
        } ?>
echo Helpers::hello_world();
```

this is work Properly but remove public static then does not work

Comment: Could you clarify, what does the question have to do with C++?

Comment: *Why* do you want to remove those keywords, and still expect it to work as is? Do you understand what `static` does?

Answer (score 3):

If you removed `static` then you'd need an *instance* of `Helpers` in order to run `hello_world()`. Currently you can reach it without an instance using `Helpers::hello_world();`.

If you replaced `public` then you might find it rather hard to access that method outside the `class`.

Best leave it as it is methinks.

Comment: "Methods declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as public. " PHP manual

Comment: Indeed. A bit like the `struct` of C++. But I've tightened up the language. Cheers.